# Extended Tic-Tac-Toe, troubles with checking winner (Java)

Tags: java, validation, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to Java and I'm making an extended version of TicTacToe (basically it differs from usual 3x3 version by the size of the game field - it could be 4x4, 5x5 and so on, the player must win a few times in a row for the final victory, etc. User can customize his game).
I have some check methods.

//1. For rows:

```
boolean checkHorizontal(String[][] field) {
                boolean valid = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < field[i].length; j++) {
                        if (!field[i][0].equals(field[i][j]) && !field[i][0].equals("[ ]")) {
                            valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return valid;
            }
```

//2. For columns:

```
boolean checkVertical(String[][] field) {
                    boolean valid = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                        for (int j = 1; j < field[i].length; j++) {
                            if (!field[0][i].equals(field[j][i]) && !field[0][i].equals("[ ]")) {
                                valid = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return valid;
                }
```

//3. And two methods for '\' and '/' diagonals:

```
boolean checkDiagonal(String[][] field) {
        boolean valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            if (!field[0][0].equals(field[i][i]) && !field[0][0].equals("[ ]")) {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

boolean checkAnotherDiagonal(String[][] field) {
        boolean valid = true;
        for (int i = 0, j = field.length - 1; i < field.length; i++, j--) {
            if (!field[0][field.length - 1].equals(field[i][j]) && !field[i][0].equals("[ ]")) {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

**Here is the problem.** For **empty** field or field like:

```
 {"[ ]", " X ", "[ ]"},
 {"[ ]", " X ", "[ ]"},
 {"[ ]", " X ", "[ ]"}
```

result of `checkHorizontal(String[][] field)` is `true`. That means there are matches, but they are not. The same is for `checkVertical(String[][] field)` and field like:

```
{"[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"},
{" X ", " X ", " X "},
{"[ ]", "[ ]", "[ ]"}
```

I combined these methods in one:

```
boolean validate(String[][] field) {
        boolean valid = false;
        if (checkHorizontal(field)
                || checkVertical(field)
                || checkDiagonal(field)
                || checkAnotherDiagonal(field)) {
            valid = true;
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

But because of the **problem**, the program does not work correctly.

I don't know how to fix this. Are the any another more good ways to check rows, columns and diagonals of 2D array? Maybe, there is some way how to do it by one universal method?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
boolean checkHorizontal(String[][] field) {
    // iterate over all rows
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        boolean validRow = true;
        // iterate over all columns
        for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length; j++) {
            // to consider a row valid, none of its cells can be empty
            if (field[i][j].equals("[ ]")) {
                validRow = false;
                break; // this row is invalid
            }
        }
        // is the row we're currently checking valid?
        if (validRow) {
            // we're done
            return true;
        }
        // try the next row
    }
    // all horizontal rows are invalid
    return false;
}
```